# Dynamically update Highcharts chart in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-redux, react-highcharts

I am using highcharts-react-official in react-redux to create a drilldown chart.

However when I click on a bar to drilldown, I also update some props which causes the component to re-render - which seems to prevent the drilldown event.

I kind of gathered from [Change series data dynamically in react-highcharts without re-render of the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805086/change-series-data-dynamically-in-react-highcharts-without-re-render-of-the-char) that I should use shouldComponentUpdate and getChart() to prevent re-render and instead dynamically update the data.

My issue is that getChart() doesn't seem to work for the official highcharts react package. I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: this.refs.chart.getChart is not a function

Is there an alternative I'm meant to be using to get and dynamically update the chart? Or some examples that I could look at?

Just including render and shouldComponentUpdate parts here:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
    //dynamically update data using nextProps
    return false;
}

render () {

    const options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            height: 300,
            events: {
                drillup: (e) => {this.drilledUp(e)}
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events:{
                      click: (e) => {this.categoryClicked(e)}
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {type: "category"},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Amount Spent ($)'}},
        series: [{
            name: 'weekly spending',
            showInLegend: false,
            data: this.props.transactionChartData.series_data,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            events: {
                click: (e)=> {this.weekSelected(e)}
            }
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: this.props.transactionChartData.drilldown_data

        }
    };
    return (
        <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
        ref="chart"
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: I lived same problem, this can be easily corrected like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65821013/11302398

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `highcharts-react-official v2.0.0` has been added `allowChartUpdate` option, which should work great in your case. By using this option you can block updating the chart with updating the component:

```
categoryClicked() {
  this.allowChartUpdate = false;
  this.setState({
    ...
  });
}

...

  <HighchartsReact
    ref={"chartComponent"}
    allowChartUpdate={this.allowChartUpdate}
    highcharts={Highcharts}
    options={...}
  />
```

Moreover, to get the chart instance use `refs`:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const chart = this.refs.chartComponent.chart;
}
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/98nl4pp5r4

Comment: ah, now that you've written it out, its so blatantly in the readme as well. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
// react native functional

import React, {useState,  useRef,useLayoutEffect} from "react"
import HighchartsReactNative from '@highcharts/highcharts-react-native'

function chartcomponent(props){
   const [options, setoptions] = useState({});
   const chartRef = useRef(null);
  

  useEffect(() => {
     // create the options for your chart.
     setoptions({chart:{}, yaxis:{}, xAxis:{},})// etc.

  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
       
        // new point to add, you can get new data via props, fetch, socket, etc.
        var x = new Date(hr.timestamp).getTime();
        var y = 10 

        // these are the important parts here:    
        var series = chartRef.current.props.options.series;
        if (!Array.isArray(series)){return;}
        var seriesdata = series[0].data;
        seriesdata.push([x,y]);
        // next line limits points in chart to 10, so new poitn replaces first point
        if (seriesdata.length>10){seriesdata.splice(0,1);}

        return () => {};
    }, [props]);


   return(
       <View style={styles.charting}><HighchartsReactNative styles={{height:300, width:600}}  options={options} ref={chartRef} ></HighchartsReactNative></View>


   )
}
```