# How can I reload chart following data update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a page with a dropdown menu, where I can select an option (data source) and load a couple charts. After that, if I select other data source charts should update as well.

When I select other data source chart is not updating. I know my variable is updating properly, also that my chart call is using this same variable.

Here a the main module

```js
function Content() {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(
    mockData.map(series => ({
      ...series,
      data: series.data.map(point => {
        const dateArr = point[0].split("-");
        return [Date.UTC(dateArr[0], dateArr[1], dateArr[2]), point[1] * 100];
      })
    }))
  );
  const handleSelectedOptionChange = evt => {
    const selectedOption = evt.target.value;
    if (selectedOption === 1) {
      setChartData(() => {
        mockData.map(series => ({
          ...series,
          data: series.data.map(point => {
            const dateArr = point[0].split("-");
            return [
              Date.UTC(dateArr[0], dateArr[1], dateArr[2]),
              point[1] * 100
            ];
          })
        }));
      });
    }
    if (selectedOption === 2) {
      setChartData(() => {
        mockData2.map(series => ({
          ...series,
          data: series.data.map(point => {
            const dateArr = point[0].split("-");
            return [
              Date.UTC(dateArr[0], dateArr[1], dateArr[2]),
              point[1] * 100
            ];
          })
        }));
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-native-select">Choose</InputLabel>
        <Select
          id="selector"
          name="selector"
          onChange={handleSelectedOptionChange}
          defaultValue={1}
        >
          <option value={1}>First</option>
          <option value={2}>Second</option>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
        <Paper>
          <CustomGUIChart data={chartData} />
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/update-data-source-m010z?file=/src/Content.js) is a "working" demo

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773491/dynamically-update-highcharts-chart-in-react) question, my `HighchartsReact` is already set with `allowChartUpdate`.

Also I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210879/reload-chart-data-via-json-with-highcharts/8408466#8408466) question, there are some solutions there. But I couldn't implement any of those. Because all of them acces the chart via `JQuery` and I don't know an alternative for the `react` case.

And [this](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36364) forum post I face the same problem as the above, it's a `JQuery` method call.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Bernardo if my answer helped you, can you please mark it as accepted? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm implementing your suggestion to my real component, it's a little bit more complex (parameterized). As soon as I get it working I'll mark it as accepted, just in case I have any follow up question or if anybody proposes a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey the problem is that you're trying to sync your props with your `CustomGUIChart` component's state and then rendering UI based on that state. Now the problem with this is that since the constructor runs only the first time the props are set to state and chart is rendered correctly, but when the props changes there's no way for your state to know that so chart doesn't change.

Now to solve this we can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` life-cycle method but instead of that a better solution is to not sync your state with your props unless you really have to. Just use your props in the render method.

Here's your code, working as expected:
https://codesandbox.io/s/update-data-source-8g27i?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js

I've made your `CustomGUIChart` component really simpler now, you can even make it a functional component

Hope it helps :)